# WPF Dynamic display and edit of data

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, barcode-scanner

I am new to  WPF. I am making an windows app which will scan a QR-code, divide its contents into multiple parts and display them under several columns as below.

e.g. (in the picture attached)
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv5vJ.png)

When a QR-code is scanned repeatedly, the Qty field is increased by 1 each time.

Can any one help me how to achieve this in my application.
(I have used datagridviews and dynamic labels in winforms, but in WPF the best recommended way?)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, how does the data arrive from your scanner? Is it an array? Or a List?
If it's an array you can easily add a new column to the grid which receives an increment value (f.e. "x++") every repeat of a foreach loop. If you upload a few code snippets I will try to  tinker something.